# rebuild fulltext catalog will invoke a full population in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, full-text-search, rebuild, population, full-text-catalog

I had set Change Tracking to Manual,when I execute

```
sp_fulltext_catalog 'myfulltextCatalog','rebuild',
```

a rebuilding is started.But I have found that the PopulateStatus of the fulltext catalog is changed to value 1,that means a full population is in progress.
      As the microsoft's Books Online says,rebuild command will not populate the catalog.So I am very confused.Anyone knows?

Answer (score 0):

oh,my god. I know the reason.

```
if Changeing Tracking!=off,rebuild will start a population.
```

But SQL Server Books Online says that rebuilding does not change any full-text metadata in the database system tables ,nor does it cause the repopulation of the newly created full-text catalog.